# How to install android target version properly [Windows]

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I know a lot of people had the same issue but none of the solutions worked for me :(

Calling `cordova requirements android` it says:

> Requirements check results for android: 
>   
> Java JDK: installed .
>   
> Android SDK: installed
>   
> Android target: not installed
>   
> Please install Android target: "android-22".
>   
> Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: C:\dev\android-sdk\tools\android.BAT
>   
> You will require:
>   
> 1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
>   
> 2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
>   
> 3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)
>   
> Gradle: installed
>   
> Error: Some of requirements check failed

Also, calling `ionic build android` in my project folder says:

> Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\DonJuwe\Desktop\box\dev\projects\myTabs\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\Users\DonJuwe\Desktop\box\dev\projects\myTabs
>   
> add to body class: platform-android
>   
> Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\DonJuwe\Desktop\box\dev\projects\myTabs\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat""
>   [Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".
>   
> Hint: Open the SDK manager by running: C:\dev\android-sdk\tools\android.BAT
>   
> You will require:
>   
> 1. "SDK Platform" for android-22
>   
> 2. "Android SDK Platform-tools (latest)
>   
> 3. "Android SDK Build-tools" (latest)]
>   
> ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
>   
> You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
>   
> Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2

I've installed both android APIs 22 and 23 (any file) as well as the latest *Android SDK Tools*, *Android SDK Platform-Tools* and *Android SDK Build-Tools* with the **SDK Manager**:

[image]

What else do I need to do in order to make that work?

Comment: try removing your SDKs and reinstalling. Make sure you use the `--save` parameter.

Comment: Shall I install the SDKs by console? I was using the manager so far.

Comment: I assume you were using *Android Studio*. If the manager is not working, try the command line. The `--save` is an NPM parameter. I don't use any IDEs, I use *Phonegap Build*, a cloud-based build tool. I don't deal with any IDE or command line stuff, not that I can't I just prefer PGB. The most common response for your issue it to reinstall. OR start over from scratch.

Comment: I am using SDK standalone and not the Android studio but I will try that.

Comment: To be clear, I am not recommending any IDEs. That was just a question.